# Resources needed for simulating 5000 virtual users, sending every 5 seconds, using Locust

Tags: jmeter, load, locust

I am trying to simulate 5000 virtual users using Locust, with each user sending a message every 5 seconds. What are the resources needed in terms of EC2 specifications in order to achieve this with some level of concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Number of users is not so important (in my experience, at least when talking about less than a couple of Users per worker), the only thing that matters is the number of requests per second.

Because the performance depends on exactly what your tests do, it is impossible to give a hard number. But the manual gives some best-case figures on what you can do with FastHttpUser/HttpUser
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html#increase-locust-s-performance-with-a-faster-http-client

> It is impossible to say what your particular hardware can handle, but in a best case scenario you should be able to do close to 5000 requests per second per core, instead of around 850 for the normal HttpUser (tested on a 2018 MacBook Pro i7 2.6GHz)

If your test plan is reasonably simple then you should be fine running at ~50% of that load.